# FlChart to display different time series

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, fl-chart

I try to use the following code for my application to display the weight of animals in a chart. My goal is a variable time controlled via buttons (e.g. 1 month, 6 months, 1 year,...).

```
             LineChart(
                          LineChartData(
                            lineTouchData: LineTouchData(enabled: true),
                            gridData: FlGridData(
                              show: false,
                              drawHorizontalLine: false,
                              drawVerticalLine: false,
                              getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
                                return FlLine(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  strokeWidth: 1,
                                );
                              },
                              getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
                                return FlLine(
                                  color: const Color(0xff37434d),
                                  strokeWidth: 1,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            lineBarsData: [
                              LineChartBarData(
                                spots: [
                                  FlSpot(0, data_snap()['Historie_Inhalt']['0']),
                                  FlSpot(1, data_snap()['Historie_Inhalt']['1']),
                                  FlSpot(2, data_snap()['Historie_Inhalt']['2']),
                                  FlSpot(3, data_snap()['Historie_Inhalt']['3']),
                                  FlSpot(4, data_snap()['Historie_Inhalt']['4']),
                                  FlSpot(6, data_snap()['Historie_Inhalt']['5'])],
                                isCurved: true,
                                barWidth: 1,
                                colors: [
                                  Colors.black87,
                                ],
                                belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                                  show: true,
                                ),
                                aboveBarData: BarAreaData(
                                    show: true,
                                    colors: [Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3)]
                                ),
                                dotData: FlDotData(
                                  show: false,
                                  getDotPainter: (spot, percent, barData, index) =>
                                      FlDotCirclePainter(
                                          radius: 10,
                                          color: Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(0.5)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                              bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                                  showTitles: false,
                                  reservedSize: 10,
                                  getTitles: (value) {
                                    switch (value.toInt()) {
                                      case 0:
                                        return '2019';
                                      case 1:
                                        return '2020';
                                      case 2:
                                        return '2021';
                                      case 3:
                                        return '2022';
                                      default:
                                        return '';
                                    }
                                  }),
                              leftTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: true, margin: 3,
                                  reservedSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 11
                              ),
                              rightTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                              topTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                            ),
                          ),
                          swapAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                        )
```

I get the following error directly for the first FlSpot:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

So far I retrieved only six fixed values from Firebase and displayed them with the following code:

```
FlSpot(5, data_snap()['P_1W_W']),
```

'P_1W_W' is in the screenshot below on the same level as 'name'.

The database looks like this ('Historie_Inhalt' is defined as an Array):

[image]